# How to upload multiple images for my product model in django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I want to upload multiple images of the product so how can I do that? Django version is 2.1 and how to store the multiple files as well.
Using python3

My model

```
class Product(models.Model):
owner = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
name = models.CharField(max_length=33, blank=True)
description = models.TextField()
postdate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=False)
duration = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
image = models.FileField(upload_to=product_directory_path, blank=False, default='default.jpg')
```

My View

```
def addProduct(request):
if request.method == 'GET':
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return render(request, 'postAd.html')

if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES.get('image'):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
        owner = UserProfile.objects.get(email=user.email)
        image = request.FILES.get('image')
        name = request.POST['name']
        description = request.POST['desc']
        pr = Product(owner=owner, name=name, image=image, description=description, category=category, price=price, ptype=ptype)
        pr.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('ors:dashboard'))
```

Comment: Create a new model "Images" with a One-to-many relationship

Comment: Thanks @sascha. Solved it by using new model

Answer (score 1):

you can try this in models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
  owner = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=33, blank=True)
  description = models.TextField()
  postdate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=False)
  duration = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
  image = models.FileField(upload_to='/image/, blank=False, 
  default='default.jpg')

class ImageProduct(models.Model):
  Product=models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  image=models.imageField(upload_to='/image/')
```

ref:
https://medium.com/ibisdev/upload-multiple-images-to-a-model-with-django-fd00d8551a1c

Answer (score 0):

> forms.py

```
from django import forms

class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    file_1 = forms.FileField()
    file_2 = forms.FileField()
    ....
    ....
    file_n = forms.FileField()
```

> add below code in your html file in order to get file attribute from forms.py.

```
 {{ form.file1 }} #for 1st file 
 {{ form.file2 }} #for 2nd file
```

> add below code in views.py and
>   No need to check user authentication in GET method (request).

```
def addProduct(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'postAd.html')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            file = request.FILES['file1']
            file1 = request.FILES['file2']

            #convert byte code to string 
            file_str = file.read().decode("utf-8")
            file_str1 = file1.read().decode("utf-8")
        return render(request, "postAd.html")
```

You can explore this project for more detail on uploading more than one file.[click here](https://github.com/bSratUoH/document-distance-calculation.git)

Comment: But how to know the number of files that will be uploaded. I think this solution works if you the number of files to be uploaded is static and not dynamic.